# How to calculate public IP address to net block to find in which net block range my IP exists?

Tags: networking, ip-address

My Ip Address is: 110.44.123.19 now I want to find region and location from IP using the below data.

**NetBlockStart,NetBlockEnd,Code,Country,Zone,City,Lat,Log**
*"455213056","455215615","NP","Nepal","Bagmati","Kathmandu","27.701690","85.320600"
"455215616","455215871","NP","Nepal","Kosi","Biratnagar","26.483100","87.283370"
"455215872","455217919","NP","Nepal","Bagmati","Kathmandu","27.701690","85.320600"
"455217920","455218175","NP","Nepal","Bheri","Nepalgunj","28.050000","81.616670"
"455218176","455218687","NP","Nepal","Bagmati","Kathmandu","27.701690","85.320600"
"455218688","455218943","NP","Nepal","Narayani","Bharatpur","27.683330","84.433330"
"455218944","455220223","NP","Nepal","Bagmati","Kathmandu","27.701690","85.320600"
"455220224","455220479","NP","Nepal","Mechi","Bhadrapur","26.544040","88.094360"
"455220480","455220735","NP","Nepal","Rapti","Tulsipur","28.130990","82.297260"
"455220736","455220991","NP","Nepal","Bagmati","Kathmandu","27.701690","85.320600"
"455220992","455221247","NP","Nepal","Narayani","Birganj","27.010430","84.877350"
"455221248","455224319","NP","Nepal","Bagmati","Kathmandu","27.701690","85.320600"
"455224320","455224575","NP","Nepal","Narayani","Hetauda","27.428390","85.032190"
"455224576","455224831","NP","Nepal","Bagmati","Kathmandu","27.701690","85.320600"
"455224832","455225599","NP","Nepal","Seti","Dhangadhi","28.707920","80.596110"
"455225600","455225855","NP","Nepal","Kosi","Koshi Haraicha","26.642937","87.371147"
"455225856","455226111","NP","Nepal","Kosi","Dharan","26.812480","87.283550"
"455226112","455226367","NP","Nepal","Kosi","Biratnagar","26.483100","87.283370"
"455226368","455230975","NP","Nepal","Bagmati","Kathmandu","27.701690","85.320600"
"455230976","455231231","NP","Nepal","Bagmati","Banepa","27.629790","85.521380"
"455231232","455237631","NP","Nepal","Bagmati","Kathmandu","27.701690","85.320600"
"455237632","455237887","NP","Nepal","Sagarmatha","Sukhipur","26.708613","86.342745"
"455237888","455240191","NP","Nepal","Bagmati","Kathmandu","27.701690","85.320600"
"455240192","455240447","NP","Nepal","Narayani","Bharatpur","27.683330","84.433330"
"455240448","455240703","NP","Nepal","Bheri","Nepalgunj","28.050000","81.616670"
"455240704","455240959","NP","Nepal","Narayani","Birganj","27.010430","84.877350"
"455240960","455245823","NP","Nepal","Bagmati","Kathmandu","27.701690","85.320600"*

This is just an example question for calculating IP to netblock.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the IPv4 address to the decimal representation of the IP address (IP Number).

Compare the number with the range in the dataset and find the corresponding location.

IP Number = 16777216*w + 65536*x + 256*y + z

where
IP Address = w.x.y.z